# Table cell widths duplicated throughout table - Undesirable

Tags: html

I have an html table. In my top table row, I have 2 td tags which widths are defined 70% and 30% respectively. Now the problem is that every row below this one which has exactly 2 td tags automatically take on these widths specified for the top row td tags, even though I specify them to be something else such as 40% and 60%.

How can I evade this generic copying of cell widths throughout the table?

Thank You

Comment: browser automaticly set up width after first row, or widest row, so if there are different, you might try create another table under with same width

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how tables in html work. Think of the columns like columns in excel, you can't have one cell in a column have a different width than another cell in the same column, disregarding colspans of course. In order to achieve something like this, you will have to use a separate table every time you want a cell to have a different width than cells in the same column in preceding rows.

Comment: Thank You, I though this might be the reason but wasn't sure

Answer (score 1):

You should look into using `<col>` and `<colgroup>` elements:

http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/tables.html#h-11.2.4

Comment: Thank you for this, kinda helps, but what I'm trying to to is really impossible, unless I use separate tables.